# Trying to inject cdi in jax-rs provider

Tags: java, jax-rs, cdi, java-7, wildfly-10

I am having an issue with wildfly 10 when trying to get a custom Transformer bean that will perform the incoming data into the form I need. I declare custom @Provider

```
@Provider
@Dependent
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class BaseProvider<T extends Base> implements MessageBodyReader<T>, MessageBodyWriter<T> {

   @Inject
   private ModelTransformer<T, String> modelTransformer;

...
```

This is the provider. In wildfly I have to specify @Dependent because the class is parametrized (Generics), but in glassfish 4 for e.g. I don't have to do that.

The problem is that the modelTransformer is null. I don't get any deployment issues, but I get NullPointerException in runtime.

This is the ModelTransformer implementation that I am expecting to be injected.

```
@Dependent
public class GsonModelTransformerImpl<T extends Base> implements ModelTransformer<T, String> {
    private Gson gson;

    ...// Specific impl of the interface that uses gson to do some stuff
```

I can't understand what I am doing wrong, but this code works on glassfish 4, and cannot get it working on wildfly 10.

I can give more details, maybe I missed something...

Thanks!

Comment: How are you packaging your app? WAR? EAR?  What does your `beans.xml` look like?

Comment: My app is war, and the bean is inside the src/main/resources/META-INF/beans.xml. The content is as follows:


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
    </beans>

Comment: WildFly 10.0 or 10.1? If it's 10.0 can you try 10.1?

Comment: I am using openshift, it has wildfly 10.. I tried on 8.2.1-Final and 9 as well.. I get the same result.